# Where, on GitHub, can I see the changes (highlighted in green and red) that I just pushed?

Tags: git, github

I pushed some changes in my repository at GitHub. everything is working fine but I cant see the exact changes in GitHub highlighted in colors as I know it. I pushed the changes with this command `git push origin master` What should I do additional to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of what you're seeing on GitHub.

Comment: So I added a screenshot for what I see, I want the changes to be displayed like here https://github.com/magnetised/mongomapper/compare/master...proxy_owner  with diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're simply looking at the *Code* page of your GitHub repository, which doesn't show changes introduced by a commit, only the version of the file stored in the tip of the selected branch.

Do the following (I've taken [one of my GitHub repositories](https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags) as an example):

1. Go back to your main GitHub page.
2. Click on the repo of interest.

   [image]
3. Click on *Code*, in the right-hand-side navigation bar.

   [image]
4. Click on the file of interest.

   [image]
5. Click *History* (next to *Raw* and *Blame*).

[image]

6. Click the commit of interest.

[image]

You should now be able to see the lines that were added/deleted in that file by that commit in green/red:

[image]